# Misbehaving CD4021BE Shift-in

Tags: arduino, shift-register

I have a CD4021BE set up very similarly to the [Arduino ShiftIn Tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftIn) (the main difference being that I don't currently have 8 buttons so have just connected PI-5 to PI-7 to ground with a resistor, I get the same misbehaviour if these are left floating).

All of the values that I'm getting are being shifted up 1 bit, so with 5 buttons connected to PI-1 to 4 and PI-8), pressing the one connected to PI-1 gives me the value `00000010`, pressing PI-2 gives me `00000100` and PI-8 just gives me `00000000`.

I have my data pin connected to Q8, which as far as I can see in the [Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/cd4021b-452614.pdf) is the right place. Just to see what happened I connected it to Q6 and get `00001000` from PI-1 and so on.

I got 5 of these chips when I ordered them and have tested 3 so far and all perform in the same way, which really just suggests that I'm doing something stupid.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
#define CLK 10
#define LATCH 9
#define DATA 8

int data;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(DATA, INPUT);
  pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LATCH, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("Begin...");
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LATCH, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LATCH, LOW);

  data = shiftIn(DATA, CLK, MSBFIRST);

  Serial.println(data, BIN);

  delay(500);
}
```

`CLK` is connected to `CLOCK` on the chip, and `LATCH` is `PARALLEL/SERIAL CONTROL`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much further googling, I found an 'answer' of sorts. [An Issue](https://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?id=467) on the Arduino implementation of `shiftIn()` with a workaround:

> There is a workaround:
>   If you turn the clock on before turning the control flag down, you avoid the extra positive clock transition.
>    digitalWrite(shiftClock, HIGH);
>    digitalWrite(shiftControl, LOW);
>   I'm not sure if this is a bug or a missing feature. The problem is that the first bit is already on the Q8 output when first positive clock transition happens in shiftIn. I think this is what is described in the datasheet as "In the HCC/HCF4021B, the CLOCK input of theinternal stage is ”forced” whenasynchronous parallel entry is made".

I added a `CLK` high between the `LATCH` pulse and it now works:

```
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LATCH, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);   // Set clock high to catch first bit.
  digitalWrite(LATCH, LOW);

  data = shiftIn(DATA, CLK, MSBFIRST);
  ...
}
```

Just when I feel like I've actually started to get the hang of things I start hitting weird bugs in the libraries!